# Shift is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple tables(with same structure)in my html. They are in tabs. I am creating tabs dynamically and i want to send those table data to the mysql database. So i wanted to get those data using javascript. I am correctly created **TableData1,TableData2....** arrays using for loop. Problem is I cannot increment **TableData** here **('TableData'+i).shift();** . I am getting an error. I want to create **TableData1.shift(),TableData2.shift().....**

```
function myDataSendFunction(){
var i;

     for(i = 1; i <= array_size; i++){
         eval("var TableData"+i+"=[];");

      $('#mytable'+i+ ' tr').each(function(row, tr){
          ('TableData'+i)[row]={
              "colum1" : $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
              , "colum2" :$(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
              , "colum3" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
              , "colum4" : $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text()
              , "colum5" : $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text()
              , "colum6" : $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text()
              , "colum7" : $(tr).find('td:eq(7)').text()
              , "colum8" : $(tr).find('td:eq(8)').text()
          }
      }); 

        ('TableData'+i).shift(); 

    }

}
```

I am getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: ("TableData" + i).shift is not a function
    at myDataSendFunction (<anonymous>:25:25)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (create.php:1)
```

Comment: `'TableData'+i` is a string, not an array. Please also don't ever use `eval()`.

Comment: You left out an `eval`, which from one perspective is not a bad thing at all. You'd be better off having `TableData` itself be an array, because then you wouldn't have to resort to that unpleasant and performance-killing use of `eval()` at all.

Comment: This is an indicator that your should rethink your code `eval("var TableData"+i+"=[];");`
Do not use `eval()` for a simple thing like that.

Comment: Sorry this is my first web development.I want to create arrays of TableData1,TableData2,TableData3.....according to the tables i am creating in the html. Number of Table is a variant. So how i create TableData1[],TableData2[].....without using eval??? Then I need to remove first row of those tables. That is why i am using shift.

Comment: **Make `TableData` an array.** Then you can use `TableData[0]`, `TableData[1]`, etc, and you can then actually do `TableData.shift();`. You simply cannot do that with plain variables (well, not in any non-horrible way).

Comment: I tried then problem occure in TableData[][row] here. **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined**

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what should i do then?? I tried with TableData array, then problem occurs in here **TableData[i][row]** with **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined**

Comment: @D.Madu - you have to set `TableData` to a value first. Like `var TableData = {}; TableData[0] = {}; TableData[0][0] = "value";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's clear that you are very new to this, so I'm going to show you first and then explain second.

```
function myDataSendFunction(){
    var i,
        TableData = [];

    for(i = 1; i <= array_size; i++){
        TableData[i] = [];

        $('#mytable' + i + ' tr').each(function(row, tr){
            TableData[i][row]={
                  "colum1" : $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
                , "colum2" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
                , "colum3" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
                , "colum4" : $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text()
                , "colum5" : $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text()
                , "colum6" : $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text()
                , "colum7" : $(tr).find('td:eq(7)').text()
                , "colum8" : $(tr).find('td:eq(8)').text()
            };
        }); 

        TableData[i].shift();
    }
}
```

Base [on your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927578/shift-is-not-a-function-in-javascript/42941865#comment72953310_42927578):

> *what should i do then?? I tried with TableData array, then problem occurs in here TableData[i][row] with Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined*

Your troubles revolve around setting properties on variables that haven't been defined. You must define `TableData` before attempting to assign a property.

Once `TableData` is "initialized" to an array (`var TableData = []`), you can set properties **on `TableData`**. But **you cannot immediately set properties *on properties* of `TableData`**. For example, you cannot jump directly to `TableData[i][row]`. You must first set `TableData[i]` to an array (`TableData[i] = []`), *and then* you can set `TableData[i][row]` to some value.

By trying to solve that problem with `eval`, you ran into a whole new world of problems. Try to avoid `eval`... it's a very complicated beast that tends to cause a lot of confusion and pain.

It may be helpful to review [MDN's Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties) documentation to better understand what's going on with JavaScript's array and objects.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your element selection is the mistake you have done. Without using a for loop by hard coding an `array_size` you could have easily

1. select all the tables at once using a common property like class. You will get an array with table objects.
2. Iterate the table objects array.
3. Inside the loop select all the rows of each table and put them into another loop to extract data and create the data array which you sends to the DB.

Find my [sample implementation here](https://jsfiddle.net/Don_D/ou2q55hk/2/).

Please do remember that when you're planning to use arrays, stick to the arrays rather than moving back and forth between strings and arrays. It will cause you problems like what you have already came across and unnecessary dirty code.